# Urgent: footnotes now not compiling

Tags: errors, footnotes, compiling, compilation-error, xfootnote

The problem is happening inside my paragraphs in ShareLatex.
/paragraph{}
Document class 12pt (report)
Was fine until I added footnotes.
Comes up with:
\@sect has an extra } but I don’t see how
\@xfootnote doesn’t match its definition. It isn’t in a section header.
Missing \endcsname inserted

I don’t see how any of these errors are happening because it was fine before I added footnotes with / symbols and full stops in them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code snippet to reproduce the error.

Comment: Delete the temporary files/recompile from scratch and try again. Don't use `\footnotes` in a `\section` argument if that's what you are doing. Please show us a short yet compilable example document that reproduces the error.

Comment: `\paragraph` is ***not*** for typesetting paragraphs. Just leave a blank line between text paragraphs and ***don't*** use `\paragraph`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you don't really want to use `\paragraph`. `\paragraph` is a sectioning command like `\section` and `\subsection`. It is not meant to create a text paragraph.

But if you want to use it, then its obligatory argument (which could move to the toc) shouldn't contain fragile commands like footnote. Then use something like

```
\paragraph[text for the toc]{Text with \footnote{bblblb}}
```